# Javascript parameters being overridden

Tags: javascript, jquery, parameter-passing, jquery-events

I have code similar to this:

```
for (i = 0; i < imageData.length; i++) {

    for (j = 0; j < sizes.length; j++){
        width = sizes[j][0];
        height = sizes[j][1];

        objectId = 'cropper-' + i + '-' + j;
        var $image = $('#' + cropperId + ' > img'),
            $preview = $('#preview_cropper-' + i + '-' + j),
            $btn = $('strict-mode_cropper-' + i + '-' + j);

        var options = {
            ...
            width: width,
            height: height,
            $preview: $preview, 
            ...
        };
        $btn.on("click", {$image: $image, options: options}, foo);
    }
}


function foo(e) {
    var $image = e.data.$image; // Gives the correct Image
    var $preview = e.data.options.$preview // Always the last $preview. Not the one that was passed in!
    var width = e.data.options.width //Also incorrect
    var height = e.data.options.height //Also incorrect
}
```

The issue is that when the user clicks on one of the `$btn`, all the fields in "options" is always the last one of the nested loop (i.e. when i = imageData.length - 1 and j = sizes.length - 1). #

Oddly enough though, the `$image` passed in is correct!

Why is this happening? How can I fix this issue?

Comment: You didn't post the code by which the `$preview` variable is set.

Answer (score 1):

In the for loop, 'options' contains the mapping

```
preview: $preview,
```

meaning that the name stored in 'options' is just 'preview'.  So you need to access preview as

```
e.data.options.preview
```

rather than

```
e.data.options.$preview
```

Comment: Sorry that was just a typo! But not the problem. But good catch

Comment: How is there a typo that didn't affect your code?  Did you copy it out by hand?

Comment: Yeah basically my actual code is a bit more complex, so I deleted the irelevent part of the code (and thus made mistakes when writing the question). Regardless, it was quite clear that was not the problem as the issue occurred with width and height as well.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick fix that I managed to do:

Instead of :

```
$btn.on("click", {$image: $image, options: options}, foo);
```

I did this:

```
$btn.on("click", {$image: $image, options: $.extend({},options)}, foo);
```

I believe this make a copy of "options" rather than pass the actual variable.

Better and more detailed answers are welcome!